# Identify if a port is closed/open/filtered using powershell

Tags: networking, powershell, scripting

Is there a way to identify if a port is closed or filtered in powershell?
The script present [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsnetdoc/archive/2011/11/07/windows-powershell-script-test-port.aspx) only checks if a connect could be successfully made. It cannot differentiate between closed and filtered.

Comment: Is wrapping nmap in powershell an option?

Comment: The script needs to be executed remotely on machines that are freshly configured. The purpose is to verify network policies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will show you if ports are filtered, or closed, but at least this will provide a bit more information:

```
clear
$port = 139
$portStats = &netstat -an |  Select-String ":$port"
$portStats
```

Comment: This does not differentiate between filtered and closed ports.